# React Formik Yup validation for checking input value less than a number

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, formik, yup

I have one form built using Formik. There are two radio buttons in the form,  when clicking one radio button an input field will appear. I need to validate that input field with Yup validation. The value should be less than 9999.99 and it may accept both integer and decimal values also. The code I tried is given below:

### Form.js

```
<RadioGroup
                    name="callBackSelectionType"
                    initialValues={[
                      {
                        value: CALLBACKREQUIRED,
                        label: "Lower callback limit",
                      },
                      {
                        value: REMOVECALLBACK,
                        label: "Reset to default $10,000",
                      },
                    ]}
                  />
                  {values["callBackSelectionType"] === CALLBACKREQUIRED && (
                    <div className="fields-container">
                      <InputField
                        label={CALLBACK_LIMIT}
                        name="greaterThan"
                        placeholder="$0.00 to $9,999.99"
                        errorMessage={getRequiredMessage(CALLBACK_LIMIT)}
                      />
                    </div>
                  )}
```

### Schema.js

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  callBackSelectionType: yup.string().required(),
  greaterThan: yup.string().when("callBackSelectionType", (val, schema) => {
    if (val === "CALLBACKREQUIRED") {
      return yup
        .number()
        .label(Labels.CALLBACKLIMIT)
        .lessThan(9999.99, "Limit should be less than 9999.99")
        .required(Messages.REQUIRED_FIELD);
    }
    else return yup.string().notRequired();
  }),
});
```

This validation works for that it is required field, but not working for the condition that it should be accept decimal and should be less than 9999.99. Please help .

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to use `.max(9999.99, "Commission should not be more than 2 digits")` ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. max will check for length of the value. right?. I need the value should be less than 9999.99

Comment: For strings it will check for the length of the string but for numbers it is going to check the value of the number

Comment: And for the two digits I would use a custom validator method (avoiding regex because I'm not that good at them and it is simpler/quicker the validation without them).
```.test("maxTwoDigits",
"Commission should not be more than 2 digits",
(number) => String(number).length >= 3
)```

Comment: return yup
        .number()
        .label(Labels.CALLBACKLIMIT)
        .max(10000, "Should be less than 10000")
        .required(Messages.REQUIRED_FIELD);
    }  This is not working , In entered a large number and not throwing error

Comment: Can you see my sandbox?
https://codesandbox.io/s/yip-number-max-test-forked-kktoc?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Thank you  for this sample. It is working there. So I think, there is some issue with my schema. Let me check

Comment: You are welcome :) hope it helps